# Openmp synchronizing within parallel for

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization, openmp

I need to do something like this

```
#pragma omp parallel{

#pragma omp for
for_1(){

   for_2(){
     do_something();
   }
   #pragma omp barrier //wait for all threads to finish after the inner for

   continue_with_something_else_in parallel();

}

}
```

The compiler tells me I can't put a barrier there. Does anyone knows how can I solve this?

Comment: The compiler is right (as it often is).  If the different threads do different numbers of iterations in the for loop, they'll hit different numbers of barriers - how would that work?   You could look into using `flush` to make sure all threads have a common view of shared variables, but given that the stuff in the parallel for loop are supposed to be independent, I'm deeply skeptical of any algorithm that requires them to have a common view of memory after the interior for loop, which again, not all threads will execute the same number of times.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thing is the inner for modifies some shared arrays and after the barrier all threads need to use the values of those arrays.

Comment: So maybe the flush directive could work?

Comment: It's possible, but read the documentation very carefully; flush doesn't always do what you might think.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but since I found it someone else might too...

## Solution:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{

#pragma omp for schedule(static)
   for_1() {
      for_2() {
        do_something();
      }
   }
   // note implicit barrier after for construct

#pragma omp for shedule(static)
   for_1() {
      continue_with_something_else_in parallel();
   }

}
```

## Explanation:

OpenMP schedules `for` loops in "chunks" and assigns them to threads, meaning that having a `barrier` in one loop iteration will be problematic, since *that same thread that is waiting* might be assigned some other loop iterations too, and so it will be waiting for itself in a deadlocked state.

But the OpenMP standard does guarantee that if you use `schedule(static)`, the same threads within a single `parallel` body are assigned the same loop iterations and can share memory efficiently, which is what I've done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link will help you:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Fcompiler%2Fref%2Fruompbar.htm

From what I see:

The omp barrier directive must appear within a block or compound statement. For example:

```
if (x!=0) {
   #pragma omp barrier    /* valid usage    */
}
if (x!=0)
   #pragma omp barrier    /* invalid usage  */
```

Comment: Hmm what does that mean? The barrier is within the parallel for but when I compile I get this error

error: barrier region may not be closely nested inside of work-sharing, critical, ordered, master or explicit task region

Comment: The compiler says everything: barrier region may not be inside a work-sharing task. #pragma omp for is a work sharing task. Look at the link I posted at "#pragma omp for"